# nginx config - pass request from subdomain to path with argument, regex in location

Tags: nginx

I have a server view.example.com, and I have to take a request like this: view.example.com/1234 - domain + 4 numbers/letters.

What i want to do is proxy_pass the request to my local service at: 192.168.33.10/view/1234

How can I write the nginx config to:

- care only about requests which match the regex (4 numbers/letters)
- pass the request along to my service.

So far I have:

```
server {
    server_name view.example.com;
    listen 80;

    location ~ '^/(?<hash>[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{4})/?$' {
        # rewrite - which I should probably use but not sure how
        proxy_pass http://192.168.33.10/view/;
    }
}
```

Arek

Answer (score 0):

just checked this one:

```
server {
    server_name view.example.com;
    listen 80;

    location ~ '^/(?<hash>[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{4})/?$' {
        rewrite ^ /view/$hash break;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.33.10;
    }
}
```

and it seems to do the trick - any better solutions ?

Arek